# how to use chart.js in webpacker rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chart.js, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I installed chart.js with yarn and in application.js I call it with `require('chart.js');`

Then I have my js file related to one view, where I want to call `new Chart` for which I get Chart is not defined. So I added it as a global with

```
global.Chart = require('chart.js')
```

but then I get Chart is not a constructor.
How to correctly import chart.js so `Chart` will be available in any view? I dont want to put my js code related to chart in application.js, I want to keep it in my separated js files.

thanks

Comment: Hello. In the documentation there is some example to import it. What you are getting in Chart when require it? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts#babel

Comment: @FábioRibeirodeCarvalho he is using chart.js not highcharts

Comment: @LeeLenalee ops, sorry

Answer (score 1):

ok with trial error I found a way
this is how I need to call it in application.js

```
require ('chart.js/auto');
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
global.Chart = Chart;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided was ok until I began facing problems in production environment due some async loads. In my case I solved this loading `Chart.js` synchronously and making it global available as following:

```
const Chart = require('chart.js/auto');
window.Chart = Chart.Chart;
```